# Different between code behind and separate C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, websocket

I have already created my application on web socket with ASP.net 4.0. I just wondering is it possible to use code behind to implement the game logic in order to create the Web Socket game or keep using the separet class? what are the main different between code behind and separate C# class?

Comment: Impossible to answer without more detail about your software architecture.

Comment: A code-behind **is** a [your language] class. Now, should you put everything in the code-behind? Of course not. The code-behind serves as the "glue" between the design-surface (markup) and the ASP.NET Control-oriented model.

Comment: Good point, nearly close to get my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason you would want to put the game logic in your code behind is to tap into the page life cycle or interact with page/form elements directly. Leave your game logic in a separate class to make it more testable.

The code-behind is "connected" to the page itself as a partial class (which is how it can reside in a separate file). Your business logic and data access should reside in a separate class to try and keep the code-behind for matters more closely related to the page itself.

Comment: Basically, separation of concerns is the main one.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it:

Code-Behind = Presentation
Class = Structure (Business logic, implementation, etc.)

So, using the code-behind is feasible but lacks re-using code or refactoring later as you're code is all in one spot. The objects should be there to allow you to compartmentalize the logic and separate it from the user interface.

Think of it like any javascript library. Sure, every web site you put out could have the whole library on its page, however its better suited as an included library that you can then reference and use on each page.

Comment: `class == structure`??  Anyway, your explanation is a bit muddy... As an experienced ASP.NET user I *think* I understand what you are saying, but there's not enough clarity here to be helpful to the OP.

Comment: actually the application already created on web socket by use of separate c# class without using code behind? for use of web socket what are the reason not to use code behind? or what are the main reason to use code behind?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I smell what you're stepping in; I guess my major premise is that _anything_ is possible in a code-behind, however keeping a separation of responsibility lacks greatly when it's all done in one file and not generalized/made common and implemented separately. I could re-connect to a database, declare a class and use it, and make a UI for the user all in a code-behind, but I'd be doing so with every code-behind. This certainly don't keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: there are some good pint but I still did not get my answer.  the application already created on web socket by use of separate c# class without using code behind? for use of web socket what are the reason not to use code behind? or what are the main reason to use code behind?